# Dynamically mark as selected an option in a form using HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, select

I am creating a form to update some entries in a sql table.

For one of the fields, I will have a Select Option that must be "selected" in the value that the field contains.

So ideally, I would have something like this:

```
<select id="source" name="source">
    <option <?=$manual?>>MANUAL</option>
    <option <?=$etsy?>>ETSY</option>
    <option <?=$online?>>ONLINE</option>
</select>
```

But I want to make it dynamic so, if I have 100 options, I won't have to write 100 variables, but just load the corresponding variable name with the word "selected".

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: updated my post. I guess it's too late =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<select id="source" name="source">
  <?php 
         $Attrib = 'selected="';
        if ($order['source'] === 'value'){
          $Attrib.= 'selected"';
        }
        else{
         $Attrib .= 'false"';
        }
  ?>
  <option name="" <?=$Attrib;?>>NAMEHERE</option>
```

Not to mention, you are assigning (`$order['source']`) to `value`, so this will always equal to "value"

Comment: How would this solution be dynamic? Meaning, if I have 100 options and all have the same variable ($Attrib) inside, then it wouldn't sort out the ones that must not be selected

Comment: @samyb8 Create an array of defaults

Answer (score 0):

May be you meant to do something like

```
<option <?= ($order['source']==='optionname')?'selected':'' ?> > optionname </option>
```

And it would be nicer to push the options to some array.
Oh, that's what u mean.

That's how i would have done it

```
<?php 
   $checkedoption = 'flytothemoon'; //the checked option
   $options = array('opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'flytothemoon');
   foreach($options as $option):?>
     <option <?= ($order['source']===$checkedoption)?'selected':'' ?> > $option </option>
   <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: The thing is I want to make it dynamic so if I have 200 options, I wouldn't need to update the code.